# WordPress won't write data from custom fields

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, chmod

My theme has a field to enter custom css code. It also has a field for the Google Analytics code. The problem is that whatever I type into these fields is gone forever once I save it and refresh the page. It is the same with the file editor under "apperance". Whatever I change here is simply not saved.

So far I have tried:

Deleting the cache plugin
Deleting all cache folder on the server
Setting all WP files and folders to chmod 777
Doing the "Permanlinks-trick" (saving anew under the permalinks section)
Deleting all cache entries out of htaccess
Deleting htaccess alltogether

...nothing worked.

As if that wasnt enough, the Visual Composer Plugin also stopped working entirely.

Iam freaking out. I can neither format nwe content nor is Google Analytics data being saved.

What is causing this insane error?

Comment: You might want to set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE` in you `wp-config.php` file